# python ctype _pack_ vs g++ #pragma pack

Tags: python, ctypes

I intent to serialize a struct like this to a "compacted" binary:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#define print(x) cout << x << endl

#pragma pack(1)

class Foo {
    uint32_t a: 1;
    uint32_t b: 2;
    uint32_t c: 5;
    uint64_t d;
};

int main() {
    print(sizeof(char));
    print(sizeof(Foo));
    return 0;
};
```

It works well here, the size of class "Foo" is 9, which is exactly what I want.

But when I try to re-implement this with Python ctypes lib, everything goes wrong.

```
import ctypes
from io import BytesIO
from ctypes import *
from binascii import hexlify

class RawMessage(ctypes.Structure):
    _pack_ = 1
    _fields_ = [
        ('a', ctypes.c_uint, 1),
        ('b', ctypes.c_uint, 2),
        ('c', ctypes.c_uint, 5),
        ('d', ctypes.c_ulong),
    ]


def dump(o):
    s = BytesIO()
    s.write(o)
    s.seek(0)
    return hexlify(s.read())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    m = RawMessage()
    m.a = m.b = m.c = m.d = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
    print ctypes.sizeof(m)
    print dump(m)
```

The size of the RawMessage is 12. I guess the "*pack*" property doesn't work at all. The binary representation of the message m is "ff000000ffffffffffffffff".

It's a confusing problem. Please help me with that.

Thanks.

Comment: I use "bitstruct" as a working around to solve the problem. Seems that "ctypes" can't really make it, or at least, can't really have a total solution the this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the sizeof of `RawMessage`to be 9, you need to use `c_uint8`for the bit-fields and `c_ulonglong` for the unsigned 64 bit field (you used `c_ulong` which is only 4 bytes / 32-bit).

python 3 code, but the idea should be transposable to python 2.7 :

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import ctypes
import io
import binascii

class RawMessage(ctypes.Structure):
    _pack_ = 1
    _fields_ = [
        ('a', ctypes.c_uint8 , 1),
        ('b', ctypes.c_uint8 , 2),
        ('c', ctypes.c_uint8 , 5),
        ('d', ctypes.c_ulonglong),
    ]

def dump(o):
    s = io.BytesIO()
    s.write(o)
    s.seek(0)
    return binascii.hexlify(s.read())

def bin_dump(byte_buff):
    s_buff = list()
    for abyte in byte_buff:
        s_buff.append("{:08b}".format(abyte))
    return "".join(s_buff)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    m = RawMessage()
    m.a = 1  # 1
    m.b = 1  # 01
    m.c = int('11111', 2)  # 11111
    m.d = 0x7ffffffffffffffe  # 1st and last bit set to 0

    # note : m.a, m.b and m.c should read: 
    # 11111 01 1 -> 11111011 -> 0xfb

    print("size of RawMessage: {}".format(ctypes.sizeof(m)))
    buf = (ctypes.c_char * ctypes.sizeof(m)).from_buffer_copy(m)
    bytes_buff = bytes(buf)
    print("buffer: {}".format(bytes_buff))

    #print(bin_dump(bytes_buff))

    print(dump(m))
```

output :

```
$> py -3 so_ctypes.py
size of RawMessage: 9
buffer: b'\xfb\xfe\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\x7f'
b'fbfeffffffffffff7f'
```